# How to determine if an email address is a Microsoft 'Work or School' account or a Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-account

I would like to authenticate against both Microsoft accounts and 'Work or School' accounts in a Azure multi-tenant environment.  Each authentication type requires different requests.  If I try to login as a Microsoft account against the 'work or school' request the login will fail at the Microsoft login and not return to my application.

Is there a way to query if a given email address is a 'Work or School' account against the Microsoft graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the REST api, it should automatically handle the two types of accounts.

However, it is in preview and might have restrictions or issues.

Here is a guide for using the REST api: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest

But be sure to check if that is acceptable to work with given the restrictions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-limitations/

Comment: I am using the rest API but get this error with Microsoft accounts.  Work or School accounts work fine against this endpoint. 

AADSTS50020: User account '***@***.***' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '***' and cannot access the application '-guid-' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: As per the instructions above, have you registered your app to implement converged auth in the Application Registration Portal?

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I didn't realize there was a new version of the API that supported combined login. I was able to test and confirm it works.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a converged Azure AD v2 of the authentication model. This [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/richard_dizeregas_blog/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model) explains how to register your app to be able to use it. It will allow you to authenticate against both Work or School Account and Microsoft account.

Also, there is a YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhGemMWFEWI).

Comment: If I don't want to authenticate, but just want to know what type of account it is, should I also use this ?